# Difficulty translating XML to CSV via XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I was looking through this link

https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/transforming-xml-to-csv-via-xslt/

which details translating XML to CSV using XSLT which is exactly the task I need to do, but I can't figure out how it relates to my data set which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
<Step Name="GetDataFromDatabase" At="2017-03-21T17:56:59.9384367-04:00">
<Result>
<R firm_id_from_source="1" firm_name="The Place" full_address="123 SOUTH MAIN  STE 123&#xD;&#xA;LOS ANGELES, CA 90071" postal_code="90071" country="United States" phone_number="213-555-1212" is_active="1" dealer_type="Friend" />
<R firm_id_from_source="2" firm_name="The Other Place" full_address="456 CENTRAL AVE  STE 456&#xD;&#xA;BEVERLY HILLS, CA 90210" postal_code="90210" country="United States" phone_number="213-555-1213" is_active="1" dealer_type="Buddy" />
<R firm_id_from_source="3" firm_name="The 3rd Place" full_address="123 NORTH MAIN  STE 789&#xD;&#xA;LOS ANGELES, CA 90072" postal_code="90072" country="United States" phone_number="213-555-1214" is_active="1" dealer_type="Friend" />
</Result></Step></Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the data is stored as attributes instead of child nodes.  You can iterate over the nodes fairly easily with `<xsl:for-each select="@*">` but selecting attributes by name is difficult in XSLT, so you'd have to count on all the records having the same attributes in the same order.